# A proxy that acts as a man-in-the-middle between my tool (which only supports http) and https sites?

Tags: http, proxy, https

I've got a tool which I need to use with a https site, but it only supports http. I need some kind of proxy tool that can work as a man in the middle between my tool and the https site, making the requests seem like http to the tool. The connection would look like this:
Tool -> HTTP -> Proxy -> HTTPS -> Site -> HTTPS -> Proxy -> HTTP -> Tool

Does anyone know of a tool or something I can set up that will work for this purpose? I've already asked in a few IRC channels and searched Google, but I was honestly not sure how to word it when searching Google, and not sure which channel to ask in via IRC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) has this capability; you can change the URL from HTTP to HTTPS on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Try [cUrl](http://curl.haxx.se/). If your tool works with stdin/out, You can pipe your tool's stdin/out through curl. Also there is the library (libCurl) that you can use from within your code, if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not code the tool and it's closed-source. It's not a commandline tool.

Answer (score 1):

Got any objection to an entire copy of Apache httpd with mod_proxy operating as a reverse proxy? Plausible instructions [here](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies).

Comment: My only objection is that I have no clue how to get that set up.

Answer (score 1):

[**WebScarab**](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project) might do it for you.  It can act as a man-in-the-middle and you can alter requests on the fly.

Comment: I already tried Burp Suite, but I need something that automatically does it. We're talking a lot of requests here, I can't do it all manually.

Answer (score 1):

"[Stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) can allow you to secure non-SSL aware daemons and protocols (like POP, IMAP, LDAP, etc) by having Stunnel provide the encryption, requiring no changes to the daemon's code."

There is also a guide on their site to [wrap HTTP requests with Stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/examples/https_windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this [SSL MITM proxy](http://crypto.stanford.edu/ssl-mitm/) can do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Nope, I need something that will act as a proxy, take http requests, turn them into https requests on the fly, get the response, and then send them back to the original tool that did the request as a seemingly http response. My tool will not allow me to enter a https url into it.

Comment: Given that the source code is available that would seem to be a reasonably trivial change to make to it.

Comment: There must be an easier solution.